# Use a pair as a parameter from another function

Tags: c++, function, return, std-pair

I have a function that returns a `std::pair<int, double>`.

I want to create another function to use the pair from the previous function and view the data in the pair, i.e. both first and second. Is it possible to pass the return of the previous function as a parameter for my new function so the second function can view the data? I am unsure about the syntax in C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
void func2( const std::pair <int, double>& data )
{

}

std::pair <int, double> func1 ( /* ... * / )
{
   //return pair
}
```

Then call

```
 func2 ( fun1( /*... */ ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like the example above:

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, double> create() {
    return std::make_pair(4, 2.);
}

void accept(std::pair<int, double> p) { }

int main() {
    accept(create());
}
```

The response is yes, you can do it.

If you don't want to pass to *accept* a copy of the pair, instead you want to submit the exact instance of it you are working with in the *main* function, you can slightly modify the functions prototype as it follows:

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, double> create() {
    return std::make_pair(4, 2.);
}

void accept(std::pair<int, double>& p) { }

int main() {
    auto p = create();
    accept(p);
}
```

And so on...

Comment: You should never specify the template arguments for `make_pair`. The whole purpose of the function template is to deduce its type arguments.

Comment: You are right, my fault in being verbose in favor of the OP.